# setCustomKey doesn't work in firebase crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

Following the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?authuser=1&hl=en&platform=android#kotlin%20ktx), I've added:

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCustomKey("my_string_key", "foo" /* string value */)
```

I'm using the latest version of crashlytics:

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.1')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
```

I've forced a crash like this:

```
throw RuntimeException("Test Crash6")
```

The crash is showing up in the dashboard, but not the custom key:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you call `setCustomKey(...)` before the crash happens?

Comment: I call setCustomKey on start of the program.

Comment: `FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCustomKey("random_key", "random_value")
throw RuntimeException("Test Crash: ${Date()}")`
It may take time crashlytics report to be available in your dashboard. If you still don't see the custom keys, you may create a sample project just for Crashlytics.

Answer (score 1):

My soultion is call recordException() before setCustomKey().
And remove your App from Recent App then open the App again.

You can retrieve the key and value in your Firebase console.
This may not be the standard way to use Firebase APIs, but it works."

Ex.

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(RuntimeException(""))
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCustomKey(somekey, someValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

in onCreate method in every activity and after:

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

write this code:

```
           Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultHandler;

        {
            defaultHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
        }

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(@NonNull Thread thread, @NonNull Throwable throwable) {
            String AymanError = throwable +
                    "\n====>>>  Error in: " + Arrays.toString(Objects.requireNonNull(throwable.getCause()).getStackTrace());

            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log(AymanError);

            FirebaseCrashlytics crashlytics = FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance();

            crashlytics.setCustomKey("ayman_string_key", AymanError /* string value */);


            defaultHandler.uncaughtException(thread, throwable);


        }
    });
```

This works for me perfectly .
it appears in crash details as here:
[image]

and in main Crashlytics menu by writing the key name :

```
key:key_name
```

Like here:
[image]